# C# Get string between two strings

Tags: c#, regex, string, ads

I have this script generated from google ads:

```
        <!-- HomePage_468x60 -->
        <div id='div-gpt-ad-1383121038726-0' style='width:468px; height:60px;'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1383121038726-0'); });
        </script>
        </div>
```

and I am trying to extract some relevant data for me, like the ad name, ad size and ad Id (So I can render the script for the head tag).

Tried using some regex like this:

```
public static String GetTextBetween(string source, string leftWord, string rightWord)
{

    return
        Regex.Match(source, String.Format(@"{0}\s(?<words>[\w\s.:]+)\s{1}", leftWord, rightWord),
                    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["words"].Value;
}
```

where I send the function the script and a left word and right word, for example in order to get the ad name ill send:

```
GetTextBetween(ad, "<!-- ", " -->");
```

But it returns with a empty string.

Can any one please help me? or does someone have any better way of doing this?

**EDIT**

I think I will use a seporate REGEX for each match, but I cant find the right expression for getting this string `div-gpt-ad-1383121038726-0`
from the string, can any one help with that?

Comment: Parse that as xml, rather than trying to use regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use regex I wouldn't use a helper "GetTextBetween" function.  I would just write one regex per situation.  But,  if you do you want to use this there will be some issues with special characters (since for leftString and rightString you want to find them exactly and not have any special symbols in them be treated as part of a regular expression. ) leftWord and rightWord will need to escape some characters for regular expressions.  I use something like this:

```
  private static string EscapeCharsForRegularExpression( string s )
  {
     //note that we must replace the \ first, because the following statements add backslashes
     return s.Replace( "\\", "\\\\" ).Replace( ".", "\\." ).Replace( "(", "\\(" ).Replace( ")", "\\)" ).Replace( "<", "\\<" ).Replace( "[", "\\[" ).Replace( "]", "\\]" ).Replace( ">", "\\>" ).Replace( "{", "\\{" ).Replace( "}", "\\}" ).Replace( "*", "\\*" ).Replace( "^", "\\^" ).Replace( "+", "\\+" ).Replace( ":", "\\:" );
  }
```

You could probably cleanup a lot of my use of double slashes by putting doing stuff like:

```
@"\["   etc.
```

Oh ... and this regex gives you your first match:

```
Regex.Matches( inputString, @"<!--\s*(.+?)\s*-->", RegexOptions.None )[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

For: 'div-gpt-ad-1383121038726-0'

```
Regex.Matches( inputString, @"'.*?'", RegexOptions.None )[0].Groups[0].Value;
```

For: div-gpt-ad-1383121038726-0 (without apostrophes around it)

```
Regex.Matches( inputString, @"'(.*?)'", RegexOptions.None )[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. but the function you wrote for escaping the string didnt help. The regex for the first match work good, I think ill just use one for each match. thanks

Comment: Can you please help me with the right regex I need in order to get this 'div-gpt-ad-1383121038726-0' from the string?